# Synchronising local git repo with remote

Tags: git

I am looking for a way to carry out the following synchronisation via git, but I haven't found an easy way to do it (aka without having to do it manually branch by branch). Probably easiest to demonstrate what i mean by 'synchronisation' is via an example.

Let's say you have a repository on github, currently with 4 branches: `master`, `branchA`, `branchB`, `branchC`. You have all four of these branches on your local repository. `branchB` is merged in to `master` (and therefore the remote branch is now closed), `branchC` gets deleted on remote - the only two live branches that remain are `master` and `branchA`. Question is, how do I synchronise my local repository with remote, to automatically get rid of `branchB` and `branchC`? I would like to do this whilst also preserving any uncommitted / pending changes in my local repositories **as long as** they are not on `branchB` and `branchC` - since they are inactive I don't care about my local changes on those anymore but anywhere else outside those branches I want to preserve everything.

How can I do this?

Comment: What about using `-p`?

Comment: @dan1st -p on what command?

Comment: I mean `git pull -p`

Comment: @dan1st what does that do? struggling to find it in the manual

Comment: @crashmstr I have about 80 branches that are no longer in use in my local repo, hence why I would only like to delete merged/deleted/closed branches and preserve the rest of them with my changes. i.e. its not going to be an exact mirror of remote, only a cleanup procedure :)

Comment: yes thank you but that doesnt help me right now @crashmstr does it, I'd rather just write a cron to clean the ~5 repos I work on at the end of each day and not waste time on it... please stop digressing or contributing if you cant help

Comment: besides its not really that easy once you work in the real world, i dont want to be spending time on manually syncing up huge repos when the PRs go through or something is deleted, there is a reason i am asking this question as i would like to stop wasting time on doing this kindof stuff manually

Answer (score 0):

Try `git remote prune origin`. It will remove any local branches no longer present in the named remote.
I advice to run this in `--dry-run` mode before to confirm you do not mess anything.

Comment: So in --dry-run I get a bunch of branches that I cant even find on our remote in merged branches, not sure why that would be? Regardless, there is still about 30 branches that this does not catch - i.e. no branches are in the prune list that are in fact merged (and therefore closed)

Comment: Are those branches tracking an upstream? This only addresses tracked branches. Not local ones.

Comment: yes all of my local branches correspond to a remote branch also, so I would assume they are indeed tracking something upstream - although im not sure if tracking continues once the branch becomes inactive on remote, I guess anything that doesnt track remote anymore should also be deleted then as they are effectively tracking a closed branch? not sure, im not that well versed in git beyond the basics

Comment: The tracking information is stored locally and supposedly, when the branch is removed from the remote, you can no longer push your changes to that remote nor pull from it.

The decision to terminate the local branch (after it has been delete from the remote) is a local decision. That automation is done by `git remote prune`. :S

Comment: ah okay I see, so in fact if i use something like `git branch -r --merged` to delete merged branches locally and then `git remote prune origin` at the end that basically should delete both merged and deleted (aka unusable) branches whilst preserving everything else?

Answer (score 0):

To do this properly, i.e. without losing uncommitted data, you would have to run dozens of Git commands. That's why high-level command-line interfaces for Git like https://github.com/git-town/git-town exist. Install it, then:

- remove the outdated branches (branchB and branchC) from your machine:
  `git town prune-branches`
- synchronize the remaining branches: `git town sync` on each branch or `git town sync --all` to synchronize all branches

Git Town stashes uncommitted changes before running and restores those changes at the end, so your local edits are safe.